# How do I print all of the instances from a set of variables that are undefined from the beginning?

Tags: python, variables

I have a program that I want to be able to print all of the instances of each variable using my method that I created. Problem is I can't figure out a way to print them since each are listed under a different variable that aren't configured from hardcoding them in and I need a way to automatically recall them in my code.

```
class fit:
    def __init__(self,day,did,workout='Not Recorded',time='An unknown amount of',calories='An unknown amount of'):
        self.day = day
        self.did = did
        if did.lower()=='no':
            self.workout = 'Not Recorded'
            self.time = "An unknown amount of Minutes"
            self.calories = "An unknown amount of Calories"
        else:
            self.workout = workout
            self.time = "{} Minutes".format(time)
            self.calories = "{} Calories".format(calories)
    def formate(self):
        self.formate = "{}:\n\nDid you work out: {}\nWorkout focus: {}\nYou worked out for: {}\nYou burned: {}\n\n----------------------------------------------------------".format(self.day,self.did,self.workout,self.time,self.calories)
        return self.formate

def reader(day,index):   
    file = open('readme.txt')
    file = file.read()
    stripped = file.rsplit("\n")
    for i in range(len(stripped)):
        stripped[i] = stripped[i].rsplit(" ")
    del stripped[-1]
    if int(index) >= len(stripped[day-1]):
        return "none"
    else:
        return stripped[day-1][index]
x = 0
def create_new_instance(class_name,instance_name):
    globals()[instance_name] = class_name(reader(x,0),reader(x,1),reader(x,2),reader(x,3),reader(x,4))
    print('Class instance {} created'.format(instance_name))
while True:
    try:
        x+=1
        ins = 'day_' + str(x)
        create_new_instance(fit,ins)
    except:
        break
    break
def printer(instance):
    print(.formate())
while True:
    x+=1
    inst = 'day_' + str(x)
    printer(inst)
```

An example of this might be that I have 8 lines of data from a text document and I have a system that creates instances of day_1, day_2, day_3 ect until day_8 and then I want to print each of those instances out, but again I don't have those instances directly hardcoded into my code so I don't know how I'd do it. I've tried looking into maybe a while loop and increasing a variable by 1 and concatenating it with day and trying to make a variable out of that but the my limited experience with python isn't helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very unpythonic and ugly way would be to use *exec*, for example:

```
day_3=5
x = 'day_'+'3'
exec("print("+x+")")
```

I would recommend another way to store your variables though.